# Combining probability and density with Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I have prior density $f(x)$, prior probabilities $p(y=0), p(y=1)$ and two conditional densities:
$$f(x|y=0) = \mathcal{N}(x, \mu_0, \sigma^2)$$
$$f(x|y=1) = \mathcal{N}(x, \mu_1, \sigma^2)$$
Where $y \in \{0,1\}$ - discrete hidden variable, $x$ - continuous experiment variable. I've found posterior **probabilities**:
$$p(y=0|x) = \frac{f(x|y=0)p(y=0)}{f(x)}$$
$$p(y=1|x) = \frac{f(x|y=1)p(y=1)}{f(x)}$$
Now it's not densities, but for $x$ I still have density, so I haven't realized what to do next.
Also I have additional info for $p_{0 prev} = p(y=0|x')$ and $p_{1 prev} = p(y=1|x')$ (I've got X form Hidden Markov Process using transition matrix, so $x'$ is the previous sample).
I don't understand how to use $p_{0 prev}$ and $p_{1 prev}$ to get more precise values $p(y=0|x,x')$ and $p(y=1|x,x')$. How to calculate it?

**Update**:
In comments @gunes told me that for HMM $p(y|x,x') = p(y|x)$. So, how can I write formula for $p(y=1|x,x')$ using $p_{0 prev}$ and $p_{1 prev}$ and prove that $p(y|x,x') = p(y|x)$?

Also, I still confused about how to combine densities and probabilities in Bayes formula (like in example above - I've got probability from densities and I don't know how to add any other information)

Comment: If this is an HMM, then $p(y|x,x')=p(y|x)$. The only arrow to $y$ is through $x$, so when it's given no additional information is needed.

Comment: @gunes Isin't $p(y|x)$ is gotten from conditional densities and prior probabilities and it doesn't take into account information from transition matrix? I thought It only takes info about noise that "hide" Markov process. Could you clarify?

Comment: the graphical model looks like below:
$$\begin{align}\cdots X'\rightarrow X&\cdots\\\downarrow\\Y \end{align}$$
So, given X, Y is conditionally independent of everything else.

Comment: @gunes Yes, I got it, it means that we use only information from densities (like we haven't realize that it's Markov process). For example if we have transition matrix [[1, 0][0,1]] (there was one switch from 0 to 1), can't we use it for more precise analysis?